# What will be the next localization for Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, localization

[In November 2012, Careers.de opened](http://blog.careers.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/11/stack-overflow-localizes-careers-2-0-in-german/). This was the first localized version of the Careers 2.0 site.

Now, is there a planning of the next localized Careers 2.0 site?

I ask of course specifically for France. We have a big lack of good sites like Careers 2.0, and if you localize the site, based on how bad we are in English, I'm pretty sure it can revolutionize the way recruiters ask us to work for them.

Comment: I wish to have http://www.careers.stackoverflow.com/in

Comment: There was UK careers at the same time as the German (though it wasn't localised in the same way - just currencies changed). I suspect the next one will be based on the number of SO users in that country, how well the current ones are doing and the ease of maintenance of this site in a non-English language (easy access to translators etc).

Comment: Some months ago we did do a full localization of the UK site. This included terminology and spelling changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the works but there is no release date set yet.  It takes a some time to clean up the site and ramp up salespeople for each language.

---

And there it is: [Feedback Wanted: Careers 2.0 in French](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179610/feedback-wanted-careers-2-0-in-french)

Comment: Awesome work, hope recruiters will come!