# Feedback Wanted: Careers 2.0 in French

Tags: discussion, jobs, feedback, localization

Careers 2.0 is making its way through Europe.  The [German launch](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/stack-overflow-localizes-careers-2-0-in-german/) went so well that we’re ready to show off the [new Careers in French](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr).   So what have we messed up?

We have a few native French speakers here at Stack Exchange, but we’d love your help in finding bugs, awkward translations, and anything that doesn’t feel right to our French users.  There are a few specific things we need your help with:

**URL** - http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr

- Are any of the translations inappropriate?  Are any of the translations misleading?
- Do the URL’s on /fr all continue to /fr endpoints, or are you getting thrown off to another site by mistake?
- Do you see any English text that has been left untranslated?
- If you venture to the employer side, is any of the pricing information not denominated in EUROS?
- Have any of the translations caused strange wrapping issues or overlapping text?

We’d really appreciate any feedback you have, and will be working throughout the week to put the final touches on the site.  Our public launch date (other than this one of course) will be on May 25th at the Rejoignez une Startup event in Paris.  And for our French Canadian friends, we’ll be following up shortly with a Careers 2.0 experience dedicated just for you.

Comment: Is it possible to enter your profile in more than one language?  At the moment it looks like you'd have to over-write the English version in order to display your profile in French.

Answer (score 20):

First of all I'm a native French speaker (Canadian French) and I don't think another version is needed for us. (For the language, maybe you meant for regional functionalities also, the € would need to be changed for $ in a Canadian version.).

I'm impressed with how good the traduction is !

### Language Problems

- I'm French I don't **Need a new password**, j'ai **Besoin d'un nouveau mot de passe** . [Right here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/employer/login?returnUrl=%2Ffr%2Fcheckout%2Fsearch) (Click on "Je suis déjà client".

[image]

- I know job offers are written by the company so you have no control over the content. Which give multi language job pages. **Job names should be translated though**

  [image]

Should be

[image]

Same goes for all the titles.

- These two labels are not translated.

[image]

It should be

[image]

Actually, the corrections should be 
Latest     => *Nouveau* 
Previously => *Précédent*

### Bugs/Glitches

- The distance will hide under the cursor once it is over 100km.

[image]

[image]

- Piecharts on [this page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/employer/search) displays off-screen tooltip.

[image]
[image]

I'll keep looking. Great job with the site :-)

Comment: We currently have no plans to ever translate user content. This means things like job titles will always be in user-who-made-it's language.

Comment: Great feedback.  What Matt mentioned above is spot on, we won't be translating any user generated content. However, we'll start working on the other suggestions.  Concerning French Canadian, it's kind of like the /uk version vs the original english version at .com.  The translations will be infrequent, but all of the currency data will be changed on the employer side.

Answer (score 17):

Via http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/cv/privacy/

[image]

Furthermore, this is a *petit problème*, but on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/cv/edit/, the colon annoying wraps onto its own line;

[image]

Comment: And of course we would have these issues when our in house French speakers aren't developers and don't have profiles.  We're on it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @WillCole Hey, I'm a french developer and I have a profile, hire me! :p

Answer (score 14):

1. in "Comment améliorer votre profil :"

   the sentence "nécessite le développement de vos accomplissements." is not really well translated. Something like "nécessite de compléter la partie accomplissements" would be better.
2. in "Formation" The label which is long collides with the modify button. (I use chromium-browser)

   [image]
3. in "vos recherches récentes": the english text is not translated
   [image]
4. in "Principales Technologies": the english text is not translated
   [image]
5. in "S'abonner à Recherche de candidats" 
   "entregistrer" is not the correct word I think, it's a bit strange. "s'enregistrer", "s'abonner" or "souscrire" would fit better.
   [image]
6. at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/account in "Atteignez plus de 20 000 000 développeurs de logiciels"  dollars are used instead of euros.
   [image]

   and also

   [image]
7. in "Test de Joël" the word "mesure" feels awkward.
   I would rather use "évaluation". The word "métrique" could have been used, but it is not as common.
   [image]

Comment: I'd post point 3 as a separate answer (or even a separate question).

Comment: @ChrisF I'm ok to post it as a separate answer, but what is the benefit ?

Comment: This question is asking for feedback on the translation process (incorrect translations, formatting errors), your point about English content is about a possible future enhancement. It would be a shame for it to get lost amongst all the "you got X wrong" posts. for the record I think it's a good feature request.

Answer (score 9):

The alignment of the text in the bottom section of this screenshot is weird (part of the "possibilité de recherche" text is over the label).

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 9):

On the "Score d'avancement" (that would sound less weird if it was something like "Etat d'avancement") under `Stack Exchange`:

- "plus de 200 dépôts" should be "plus de 200 points"

On the profile page:

- "intéressé par poste à temps plein" should be "intéressé par un poste à temps plein" or "intéressé par : poste à temps plein"
- "Premier XX%" should be "Premiers XX%"
- Under `Applications et logiciels` -> "ajouter une candidature..." should be "ajouter une application..."
- Under `Formation` -> when adding/editing, between the 2 dates, instead of being `XXXX chez XXXX` it should be `De XXXX à XXXX`
- Under `Expérience` -> same problem
- Under `Certifications` -> same problem

On the `fr/users/info` page:

- "les envoyer par e-mail" -> "e-mail" should be enough (if compared with the english page)

On the home page:

[image: home]

- The `placeholder` text is too long (or the field too small...)
- "lieu" should be "lieux"

On the job description page, at the very bottom:

- "publié le" -> "publiée"

Answer (score 7):

1. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/faq: "FAQ des employeurs" is translated, but next section "FAQ For Programmers" isn't translated and should read "FAQ des programmeurs."
2. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/privacy-policy:
   first paragraph:
   ...avec comme objectif modeste d'améliorer **Internet**.

   - Suggested correction:  avec comme objectif modeste d'améliorer **l'internet**.
3. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/support: "Vous avez besoin d'aide, vous n'arrivez pas à la trouver ou vous souhaiter parler à quelqu'un"

   - Suggested correction:  ou vous **souhaitez**

Answer (score 3):

from the faq:

### Qu'est-ce que Careers 2.0 ?

> Les programmeurs peuvent lancer des recherches dans notre tableau de
>   bord d'offres d'emploi et envoyer leur CV pour postuler à l'un des
>   plus d'un millier de postes à pourvoir, ...

"à l'un des plus d'un millier de postes" is not really nice. I don't have a great replacement. Maybe the following is slightly better:

> Les programmeurs peuvent lancer des recherches dans notre tableau de
>   bord d'offres d'emploi et envoyer leur CV pour postuler à un poste
>   parmi un choix de plus d'un millier d'offres, ...

Although this second version is not perfect.

Edit: I think this text block should be formulated differently. At the moment it feels a bit unnatural.

### Combien de candidats se trouvent-ils dans votre répertoire ?

Encoding issue:

`Notre répertoire compte 109&#160;765 candidats`

Comment: Since you're at it, you should mention “se trouvent-ils”. The whole sentence should read “Combien de candidats y a-t-il dans votre répertoire ?”.

Answer (score 3):

The translations are very good, there is very little tiny points that might be improve:

First, I think the text in the banner is false:

[image]

Should be `at our French language site`

On the [main](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/) page

- `offres d'emploi en vedette` seems like a google translation. I propose `offres d'emploi vedettes` or `offres d'emplois intéressantes`

On the profil page

- `Premier X%` should be translated back to `Top X%`. Maybe it is a debatting translation, but `Premier X%` is far too formal.

On the [invitation](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitations) page

- `lorsque vous : Dites-en plus sur vous` doesn't ring well. Try `lorsque vous : En dite  plus sur vous`

On the [privacy policy](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/privacy-policy) page:

- the paragraph

> Votre navigateur nous donne également votre adresse IP, qui peut être
>   utilisée pour vous identifier, mais nous ne l'utilisons pas à cette
>   fin. Parole.

The "**Parole**" is weird. You should translate it by "**Promis**" instead. And even "**Promis juré craché**" if you want it to be funny.

- the paragraph

> Si vous nous communiquez votre adresse électronique, il peut arriver
>   que nous vous envoyions des messages. Mais sans doute pas très
>   souvent. Nous aussi sommes assez occupés.

I don't think the last sentence is correct. I think instead

> Nous aussi nous sommes assez occupés

- A strike have been put on the wrong emplacement

> free <strike>transportation by unicorn</strike> transit cards.

Have been translated by

> <strike>cartes de transport gratuit</strike>

instead of

> cartes de <strike>course de licorne</strike> transport en commun gratuit

- There is an inapropriate `i` in the word `collections` in the sentence

> Nous collections ces informations ne permettant pas de vous identifier...

instead of

> Nous collectons ces informations ne permettant pas de vous identifier...

- The word `en` is repeated in the sentence

> (en en supprimant toute informations pouvant permettre de vous identifier personnellement)

- The plural form for `toute information personnelle` should be better:

> Avant de fournir toute information personnelle aux agents, nous obtiendrons
>   l'assurance qu'ils les protégeront conformément à cette politique
>
> Avant de fournir toutes informations personnelles aux agents, nous obtiendrons 
>   l'assurance qu'ils les protégeront conformément à cette politique

Comment: “The plural form for *toute information personnelle* should be better”. No using the plural is clearly a mistake. The singular is what is expected. *Toute* means “any” in this context. *Toutes* is just wrong. But *Toutes vos* would be “all your personal data”!

Answer (score 3):

In the Privacy Settings: the "make my profile public" and "make my profile private" are reversed: if my profile is currently public, it should say "make my profile private" and vice versa.

[image: Bug]

---

Also when visiting the site from France, we get this message:

[image]

"Vous visitez de la France?" is incorrect. "Vous êtes français ?" would be better.

Comment: The intended is maybe “Vous visitez ce site depuis la France ?” (asking for location, not nationality).

Answer (score 2):

On [my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/jj) I get:

> Actuellement President chez **Prologinet** Oral examiner in computer science chez Lycée Louis le Grand, Paris.

The English equivalent being:

> Currently a student. Currently President at **Prologin, and** Oral examiner in computer science at Lycée Louis le Grand, Paris.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you see any English text that has been left untranslated?

I found the 'Open Source' listing page (Click on the Mon profil's ***autre...*** link under the OPEN SOURCE section) where it's still displayed partly in French and English.

Here is the screenshot of the same:

> [image]

---

**FIXED**: As of 9/21/2015 I can confirm everything as suggested *below* has been corrected. Thank you for fixing this!

I found few places under "**My Profile**" (Mon profil) where it's still displayed partly in French and English. Especially the 'JOB STATUS' first sentence i.e. "Your profile is currently set to block all messages and searches."

Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Also, in the footer the link says **why stack?** ('why' needs fix). And, when you visit the 'why stack?' page at the bottom of page it shows:

[image]