# Careers in French still shows English user data

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The idea of a [Careers 2.0 in French](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179610/feedback-wanted-careers-2-0-in-french) is really good, but I still only have a single profile. All my current profile information is in English, not just because that was the only language Careers supported, but also because I'm targeting employers outside of France. With the new option to display Careers in French, all the titles and headers are in French, but my entries are still in English. Can you add a feature to translate, but keep the English data for the English Careers site?

Answer (score 4):

I think the win here is to allow you to have multiple CV's.  A CV per language you're fluent in.  We took a look at all the computer translations, and they're awful.  And paying professional translators to do user generated content is extremely complicated and expensive.

This isn't a "right around the corner" feature, but we have been thinking about the idea and will update once it's closer on our schedule.

Comment: I don't want automatic translate, or paid translator. To have the possibility to do it myself would be a good first step.

Comment: @Stephane I think that's what Will meant... he was just ruling out the possibility of automatic translation of CVs into different languages.