# How did Stack Exchange decide to show a banner ad for French Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, jobs, advertising

I received the banner ad for [Careers 2.0 in French](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179610/feedback-wanted-careers-2-0-in-french).

What made it decide to do that?

Was it because I asked [Learning a bit of French with not much time](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6316/learning-a-bit-of-french-with-not-much-time) on the French Language and Usage site?

Was it because I spend a bit of time at the other language sites, including Japanese Language & Usage, and English Language Learners?

Was it random?

Does Stack Exchange follow my twitter feed and notice me responding to someone's pleas for help with French?

Is it mainly happening to [Aussies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179966/38765)? Have they got us confused with [New Caledonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Caledonia)?

Comment: Stack Exchange knows what you did last summer....

Comment: French is clearly taking over the world. Google started appearing in french last week at our house.

Comment: My computer is french localized but I don't see any ad on SO in french (not even the one for careers 2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was totally random... These should have been geo targeted to the French market but were not. This has been remedied (+1 for New Caledonia theory).